# PHP code not working from file:// URL

Tags: php

It's been a few months since I've used PHP so I'm assuming I'm just forgetting something trivial.  No matter what PHP I put into my .php file, the PHP part doesn't run.  Even something as simple as this

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php 
            echo "hey";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

doesn't work--it produces a blank page.  Thanks for your help!

EDIT:  I forgot to mention that I'm viewing the pages in my browser by typing in the file location into the URL.  Ex) `file:///C:/Users/Student/Documents/test.php`

Comment: Does your file have a `.php` extension?

Comment: Are you running that locally? If so do you have xampp or something similar set up to run PHP?

Comment: And what do you see if you do a view source of the blank page?

Comment: blank page = something blew up and display_errors is not enabled. that or php isn't configured properly and the php code is leaking through into the browser. do a view source to check on that.

Comment: There is no problem with that whatsoever. I suspect you are running it on a local machine with no PHP engine.

Comment: do you have a phpservice running?

Comment: @George I think that is the case.  It has a .php extension and when I view page source, it comes up with the code from my .php file.  I am connected to SecureCRT, but honestly I'm not very versed in things like this so I don't quite know what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
file:///C:/Users/Student/Documents/test.php
```

**This URL** is opened by your browser from the local filesystem. PHP is executed by a webserver. The browser doesn't understand PHP. Your PHP after execution by server generates HTML which is finally displayed by your web-browser.

So, you should host a local webserver and access it as `http://localhost/xxx.php,` if you want the PHP to execute. **[Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)** perhaps.

Comment: ...You should try WAMP Server

Answer (score 1):

You need a PHP service, XAMPP is just one possibility.

- http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Answer (score 1):

You will need a program to run and process the php-files "server-side", thus making your pc like a webserver for php files.
Xampp should work just fine: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a webserver, such as XAMPP or WAMP, and run your files as `localhost/test.php`. PHP can't be parsed by browsers by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Apache Server already, check your Apache Logs.

Answer (score 0):

When writing PHP I use [Mamp](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) to create my server environment. It's super easy to configure and free. there is a pro option that comes with the download but you can safely delete that.